# Tensorflow lite ValueError: The size of the validation_data (0) couldn't be smaller than batch_size (64)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, tensorflow-lite

I am experimenting with tensorflow lite with a script like this:

```
import numpy as np
import os

from tflite_model_maker.config import ExportFormat, QuantizationConfig
from tflite_model_maker import model_spec
from tflite_model_maker import object_detector

from tflite_support import metadata

import tensorflow as tf
assert tf.__version__.startswith('2')

tf.get_logger().setLevel('ERROR')
from absl import logging
logging.set_verbosity(logging.ERROR)


train_data = object_detector.DataLoader.from_pascal_voc(
    './train',
    './train',
    ['person','laptop','cup','bottle']
)

val_data = object_detector.DataLoader.from_pascal_voc(
    './validate',
    './validate',
    ['person','laptop','cup','bottle']
)


spec = model_spec.get('efficientdet_lite0')


model = object_detector.create(train_data, model_spec=spec, batch_size=4, train_whole_model=True, epochs=20, validation_data=val_data)
model.evaluate(val_data)
```

And I keep getting hung on the `model.evaluate(val_data)` with an error:

```
ValueError: The size of the validation_data (0) couldn't be smaller than batch_size (64). To solve this problem, set the batch_size smaller or increase the size of the validation_data.
```

Where if I understand it correctly....I need a bigger validation test set? But the error doesnt go away if I move images from train to validate in an attempt.

- Number of images in my `train` directory: `153`
- Number of images in my `validate` directory: `66`

Any tips appreciated not a lot of wisdom here...

Answer (score 0):

This whole problem turned out to be an error in the path name to the folders of the training/validate directories.

```
print(len(train_data))
print(train_data)
```

Was zero and nothing...so I was expecting that the tensorflow would through a directory path error but if the directory doesnt exist it will just be zero and cause this error